# How to return item index from list SML?

Tags: list, sml

I have go a problem with function in SML. This function should return list index of number which will not be summed, but was taken to sum.
A call of a function: index(10, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
Result should be 3 
(10 is a sum of numbers, we seek an index from the list which gives us 10, e.g:
1+2+3=6, 1+2+3+4=10, and return previuos one)

```
fun index (sum : int, numbers : int list) =
    if null numbers
    then 0
    else if hd(numbers) > sum
    then 0
    else 1 + index(sum, (hd(numbers)+(hd(tl numbers)))::(tl numbers))
```

It seems to work, but result is wrong.
Function increments the result every two calling even if it should not.
Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. While I agree with @koodawg that adding a counter and a running total is another solution for this problem, having those in your code will complicate it more than it needs to be.

First, I have a few comments about your code. You must remove the unnecessary parens. `hd(numbers)` is same as `hd numbers` and `(hd(tl numbers))` is equal to `hd(tl numbers)`. So your `(hd(numbers)+(hd(tl numbers)))` could be simplified to `(hd numbers + hd(tl numbers))`. Also, you can combine `if null numbers` and `if hd(numbers) > sum` in a single condition for code brevity since they yield the same result: `0`.

I'll try to explain how code works and I hope you'll get the idea where you have to amend your code.

Using your example, `index(10, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])`, **your code execution will be like this:**

1)

```
 fun index(10, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 1 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [1 + 2] append to [2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [3,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

2)

```
 fun index(10, [3,2,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 3 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [3 + 2] append to [2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [5,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

3)

```
 fun index(10, [5,2,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 5 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [5 + 2] append to [2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [7,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

4)

```
 fun index(10, [7,2,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 7 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [7 + 2] append to [2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [9,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

5)

```
 fun index(10, [9,2,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 9 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [9 + 2] append to [2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [11,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

6)

```
 fun index(10, [11,2,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 11 > 10 
     then 0
```

**result:** 0

To sum all results: 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 5 (just like what you said that your function adds 2 to the expected result)

**The correct code must behave like this:**

1)

```
 fun index(10, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 1 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [1 + 2] append to [3,4,5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [3,3,4,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

2)

```
 fun index(10, [3,3,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 3 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [3 + 3] append to [4,5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [6,4,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

3)

```
 fun index(10, [6,4,5,6,7]) =
     if 6 > 10 
     then 0 
     else 1 + (10, [6 + 4] append to [5,6,7])
```

**new list:** [10,5,6,7] 
**result:** 1

4)

```
 fun index(10, [10,5,6,7]) =
     if 10 > 10 
     then 0
```

**result:** 0

To sum all results: 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 3 which is the expected answer.

**HINT:** You always make sure that the new list your function is processing must be smaller than the previous list/original list.

I hope I explained clearly why your code isn't working. I didn't include the code because I know this is a homework for an online class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a counter and total. Counter that increments with every recursive call, total equal to sum of each hd(numbers) as you go, then return the counter when your total > sum.

Something like this;

```
if (total + hd numbers) >= sum
then counter
else recursivecall(total + hd numbers, tl numbers, counter + 1)
```

Comment: Does this mean that 'else if' statement' or 'else' statement are wrong?

Comment: Returning 0 to indicate that the list is empty is certainly wrong, since index 0 also refers to the first number in the list.